# Remove static files from Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I used to have a static file called `test.html`. Now I need to put a 301 redirect instead of this file, so I wanted to use a simple Servlet to do it. The problem is that App Engine still returns static file instead of using mapped Servlet. Is there a way to remove static files from server? If not, are there any other solutions to implement 301 redirect?

Comment: For testing purpopes, have you tried to add a stub query string on the url? Like `test.html?1`. The servlet is correctly called?
Are you sure the problem you're experiencing is not related to the browser cache?

Comment: Is test.html still in your WAR file? From the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Servlets_and_URL_Paths): Note: Static files, files that are served verbatim to users such as images, CSS or JavaScript, are handled separately from paths mentioned in the deployment descriptor. A request for a URL path that matches a path to a file in the WAR that's considered a static file will serve the file, regardless of servlet and filter mappings in the deployment descriptor. You can exclude files from those treated as static files using the appengine-web.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the static file was still in the `.war` file. I had to clear the `target` directory and it worked after that.

Thanks for the useful comments.